# Git orphan branch still shows history

Tags: git, github

My understanding of `git checkout --orphan` is that:

> Create a new orphan branch, named , started from  and switch to it. The first commit made on this new branch **will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history totally disconnected from all the other branches** and commits.

So I want to use this approach to track dotfiles from different machines in the same repo, just under independent branches.

I created "dotfiles" repo on GitHub and ran the following on my Mac:

```
git checkout --orphan mac
git add .zshrc
git commit -m "Added zshrc"
git remote add origin https://github.com/*<name>*/dotfiles.git
git push --set-upstream origin mac
```

Then basically did the same on my raspberry pie

```
git checkout --orphan rpi
git add .zshrc
git commit -m "Added zshrc"
git add .emacs
git commit -m "Added emacs"
git remote add origin https://github.com/*<name>*/dotfiles.git
git push --set-upstream origin rpi
```

Everything worked fine and I have 2 branches, except on GitHub the rpi branch shows that

> This branch is 2 commits ahead, 1 commit behind mac.

How is this possible? If:

> have no parents and totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits

Or is my understanding of --orphan option incorrect?

Comment: The ahead/behind counts are based on the *upstream* setting. Any branch can have one upstream setting, regardless of parentage. The count is simply the result of `git rev-list --count --left-right name...upstream`, i.e., the symmetric difference (note the three dots). If the two subgraphs are disconnected, every commit on the left-side branch is disjoint from every commit on the right-side branch so the counts will be the same as `git rev-list --count <name>` and `git rev-list --count <upstream>`.

Comment: Or, in shorter terms: that's normal and correct output.

Comment: How can you have 2 remotes with the same name of `origin`?

Comment: @Kata I'm pushing to the same repo but into separate branches.

Comment: @torek But I thought that both MAC and RPI orphan branches are completely separate from each other, so they should not even see each other and know of each other's commit history?

Comment: Git doesn't care whether the sets are disjoint, it just enumerates them. Both sets of commits are in one repository, so one `git` command can walk through both subgraphs.